# Bad Practice - Optimizing Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have worked around SQL for about 2 years now doing basic queries (select and update statements). I have recently decided to start to learn a bit more about the queries I have been writing. I bought Training Kit (Exam 70-461) Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and during the initial couple of chapters it speaks a bunch about Query optimization and performance. I may be getting ahead of myself but this has always intrigued me.
In writing a query for a custom report I found myself writing a Select statement inside of an Attribute. I read that this is terrible for performance and I would like to avoid doing this.

Here is the Attribute I am trying to select for my query.

> `(LEFT(DATEADD(HOUR, -4,(CAST((Select Table2.Column1 from Table2 where [Text] = N'TextString.' and Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column2) AS Time))),8)) as "End Time"`

```
SELECT
    CAST(TABLE1.column1 AS date) as Date
    , DBO.Table2.column2 AS [Table2 ID]
    , CASE [queueID]
        WHEN 2 THEN N'Scenario 1'
        WHEN 3 THEN N'Scenario 2'
        WHEN 4 THEN N'Scenario 3'
        WHEN 5 THEN N'Scenario 4'
        WHEN 6 THEN N'Scenario 5'
        WHEN 7 THEN N'Scenario 6'
        WHEN 8 THEN N'Scenario 7'
        WHEN 9 THEN N'Scenario 8'
        WHEN 10 THEN N'Scenario 9'
        ELSE N'Scenario 10'
    END AS "Name"
    , RIGHT (Column5,11) as "Number"
    , LEFT (DATEADD(HOUR, -4, (CAST (TABLE1.column1 AS time))),8) as "Start Time"
    , LEFT(DATEADD(HOUR, -4, (CAST((Select TABLE1.column1 from TABLE1 where [Text] = N'TEXT STRING.' and [Table2].column2 = TABLE1.column2) AS Time))),8) as "End Time" 
FROM
    [CcMain].[dbo].[Table2] WITH (NOLOCK)   
    INNER JOIN TABLE1 WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON TABLE1.column2 = [Table2].column2
WHERE
    ([Table2.Column3] =N'8' Or Table2.Column3 is null) 
    AND [Column4] IS NULL 
    AND CAST (StartTime AS date) = DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(date, SYSUTCDATETIME(),101))
    AND [Text] = N'TeXT string 2.'
;
```

Comment: the query is doing multiple conversions/typecasts on data, which means indexes cannot be used - none of the results from all those conversions are kept after the query's done, which means they have to be REDONE every time the query runs. e.g. it forces a full table scan and bypasses indexes.

Comment: Post the entire select statement

Comment: Not sure about performance, but in terms of clarity, it's not very good.

Comment: Why is this tagged both `sql-server` and `mysql`?

Comment: I have posted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a subquery to do a join.  It probably would be better to write this as a Table1 JOIN Table2 ON  TAble1.Column1 = Table2.Column2.

However, that doesn't mean you should never do SELECT's in subqueries.  Rather, you should avoid them when they are unnecessary.